# How to use Google Language API to add multilingual in the website using PHP language?

Tags: php, multilingual

I have created a website, I want to add 3 languages(Taiwan, China, English) for this website - multilingual website. 
I've tried to find Google Language API tutorial, but I really very understand their guideline and don't know how to use it. Do yours have some simple coding example can introduce for me to refer to add multilingual in the website? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Following url:

It's example of google language to add in site

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-google-translate-button-webpage/

Comment: do you have any reference for implementing this in backend , i am using fastapi

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to translate with google :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But why I've tried it no show the translate select box

Answer (score 0):

Adding Google Translate API is very simple to implement. You can add Google translate script by following these steps.

**Step 1:** Set up CDN Path for Google API.
**Step 2:** Set up a div element to place Translator.
**Step 3.** Set up Default Language for the Webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title> Google Translater for Website </title> 
</head> 
<body>
<h2>Your Web Page</h2>
 <p>Click on the dropdown button to translate.</p>
 <p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy this code and run it on any Editor.
Source: https://www.coderepublics.com/howto/how-to-google-translate.php